# How to create an icon for HTML?

Tags: html, image, icons, html-head

How do I create an icon for my web page? Google has an icon: 
[image]
I already created an icon, but I want to add it to my web page. Please help me with this question (I tried to show the image, but I failed [image]
).

Answer (score 3):

These are called favicons, short for favourite icons.

There are various [websites](http://www.favicon-generator.org/editor/) where you can design them online

If you already have an icon designed you need to add this code to the head of your html and change the link to reference the location of the icon in your files.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Different devices support different resolutions for favicons. The default size is 16x16 however many support higher resolutions which allow for a more detailed icon. If you design a basic image you can use this [website](http://www.favicomatic.com/) where it will convert it to the .ico format and allow you to produce the sizes you need to take advantage of all devices resolution support.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Use http://www.favicon-generator.org/ for easy favicon creation.
This creates it and gives you the code to embed also.